# Inserting words from text file into commands

Tags: text-processing

I have a text file with a list of over 100 single words, one word per line:

```
Oliver.txt
Jack.txt
Noah.txt
Leo.txt
William.txt
```

I want to convert the text file content to

```
gallery-dl -g -i Oliver.txt > OliverX.txt
gallery-dl -g -i Jack.txt > JackX.txt
```

And so on for all words. How I can achieve this?

Comment: What do you want to convert it to? Add the expected output to the question. Also, why are you using `gallery-dl` with a text file? It's for image galleries.

Comment: It's unclear whether you just want to output the final result as _text_, or whether you want to actually _execute_ the commands that you create.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In GNU awk:

```
awk -i inplace -v FS="." '{print "gallery-dl -g -i " $1 ".txt > " $1 "X.txt"}' FILE
```

It'll replace contents of *FILE* with the new contents. Remove `-i inplace` if you want to have new contents printed to stdout and have
an original contents of *FILE* intact.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily and with almost the same syntax in `perl` or `sed`:

`sed`:

```
$ sed -E 's/(.*).txt/gallery-dl -g -i \1.txt > \1X.txt/' file
gallery-dl -g -i Oliver.txt > OliverX.txt
gallery-dl -g -i Jack.txt > JackX.txt
gallery-dl -g -i Noah.txt > NoahX.txt
gallery-dl -g -i Leo.txt > LeoX.txt
gallery-dl -g -i William.txt > WilliamX.txt
```

`perl`:

```
$ perl -pe 's/(.*).txt/gallery-dl -g -i \1.txt > \1X.txt/' file
gallery-dl -g -i Oliver.txt > OliverX.txt
gallery-dl -g -i Jack.txt > JackX.txt
gallery-dl -g -i Noah.txt > NoahX.txt
gallery-dl -g -i Leo.txt > LeoX.txt
gallery-dl -g -i William.txt > WilliamX.txt
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. But I forget to mention that the base file the list of words is actually Oliver.txt, Noah.txt, Leo.txt . When I ran your method. I got $gallery-dl -g -h Oliver.txt.txt > Oliver.txtX.txt

Comment: @user1757774 please make sure your question accurately represents your data. We can only work with what you show us so please edit your question and correct it, then I can update the answer.

Comment: Yeah I have corrected it. Sorry

Comment: @user1757774 see updated answer

Comment: @terdon this brief note explains points relevant here [\1 vs $1](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Warning-on-%5C1-Instead-of-$1)

Comment: @guest_7 thanks. And yes, I don't think I ever use it in scripts, I just find it practical here to have the same syntax between perl and sed and in this case there are none of the issue mentioned in the note.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -pe 's/ ^ (.+) \.txt $ /gallery-dl -g -i $0.txt > $0X.txt/;'
```

Similar to @terdon's Perl(5) code, Raku's captures start from `$0` instead of 1 as in Perl(5). The code above with `(.+)` demands at least one character before the `\.txt` extension. All non-`alnum` characters in the left half of Raku's `s///` substitution operator must be escaped to be understood as literals (e.g. `\.txt`). Finally, the left half of Raku's `s///` substitution operator is whitespace-tolerant by default.

Sample Input:

```
Oliver.txt
Jack.txt
Noah.txt
Leo.txt
William.txt
```

Sample Output:

```
gallery-dl -g -i Oliver.txt > OliverX.txt
gallery-dl -g -i Jack.txt > JackX.txt
gallery-dl -g -i Noah.txt > NoahX.txt
gallery-dl -g -i Leo.txt > LeoX.txt
gallery-dl -g -i William.txt > WilliamX.txt
```

https://raku.org